# How to install a bin file on virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, binary-files

I downloaded a .bin image of Cloudready OS and want to install it on VirtualBox. How do I do it? Apparantely VB doesn't take bin files. Is there any way or do I need to convert bin to iso?

Comment: `WinBin2Iso`, `WinISO`, `AnyBurn`

Comment: Can you use VMware instead? VirtualBox will only run old versions according to the instructions here : https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-run-chrome-os-in-virtualbox/  Otherwise you could try to rename `.bin` to `.iso` as per their docs : https://cloudreadykb.neverware.com/s/article/Can-I-get-an-ISO-file-to-install-CloudReady

Comment: @lx07 Thanks for the links. I will definitely try VMWare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some easy solutions!

You don't need VMWARE for this. You have two options:

1. Convert the Bin file into a virtual disk image by running this very simple line of code on your terminal:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw original_bin_image.bin targetname_converted.vdi --format VDI
```

Then you simply attach or add to your VirtualBox and set it to boot it.

---

The second option is a workaround. You can download VENTOY which is a booting system in his free live version and attach it to a regular cd on your virtual machine. This will allow you to boot into the Ventoy booting system and select your bin file to get booted :)

---

Bonus Solution:

If you haven't managed to follow the instruction correctly on the previous solution steps.... then you can simply do the easiest thing. Burn the bin file into a pen USB and loaded on the virtual machine marking the setting LIVE.

To burn the bin file in a pen usb you can simply type this on the terminal:

```
sudo dd if=file.bin of=/dev/sdX bs=4M status=progress
```

MAKE SURE TO REPLACE THE "X" on sdX with the correct number associated with the pen USB of destination.